# update/delete/insert a List in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I have a little problem to understand how it make sense to insert a List of languages in JPA for a Oracle 19 DB.

The API receives a DTO with a list of chosen languages for one user.

```
{
    "userId": 173125,
    "logname": "testor2",
    "lastname": "Testimator2",
    "firstname": "Testor2",
    "selectedLang": [
        "German",
        "English"
    ],
}
```

The Table looks like this for User and had a Table with pk and fk for user and language code.

The Table should remove unused languages that not in the received DTO || insert new languages in the table that not exist.
Tables that used in the db are:

USER

| Columnname | Type | keys |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USERID | int | PK |
| LOGNAME | row | - |
| NAME | varchar | - |
| LASTNAME | varchar | - |

USERLANGUAGE

| Columnname | Type | keys |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USERLANGUAGEID | int | PK --part of primary key |
| USERID | int | PK --part of primary key |
| Languagecode | varchar | - |

Now the tricky part. I want to store the languages as a List and have thought that jpa deals with the update, remove or inserts itself.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "test")
public class UserEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "USERID", nullable = false)
private long userid;
@Column(name = "LOGNAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String logname;
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 60)
private String name;
@Column(name = "LASTNAME", nullable = false, length = 80)
private String lastname;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userid", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<UserlanguageEntity> languages;

public List<UserlanguageEntity> getLanguages() {
    return languages;
}

public void setLanguages(List<UserlanguageEntity> languages) {
    this.languages = languages;
}

public UserEntity addLanguage(UserlanguageEntity userlanguageEntity) {
    languages.add(userlanguageEntity);
    userlanguageEntity.setUserid(this);
    return this;
}

public UserEntity removeLanguage(UserlanguageEntity userlanguageEntity) {
    languages.remove(userlanguageEntity);
    userlanguageEntity.setUserid(null);
    return this;
}
}
```

UserLanguageEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USRLANGUAGE")
public class UsrlanguageEntity {


@EmbeddedId
private UserId user;

private String languagecode;

@Basic
@Column(name = "LANGUAGECODE", nullable = true, length = 4)
public String getLanguagecode() {
    return languagecode;
}

public void setLanguagecode(String languagecode) {
    this.languagecode = languagecode;
}

public UserId getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(UserId user) {
    this.user = user;
}
...
}
```

Embedded ID

```
@Embeddable
public class UserId implements Serializable {

@SequenceGenerator(name = "userlanguageid", sequenceName = 
"USERLANGUAGEID", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
"userlanguageid")
@Column(name = "USERLANGUAGEID", nullable = false, precision = 0)
private long userlanguageid;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "USERID")
private UserEntity userid;
...
}
```

So the fetch method is fine and works as intended, but when i want to update the languages I get errors.
First of all get the list out of db to an UserEntity, then want to clear the UserLanguageEntitylist -> the list in the UserEntity. And than add the received list, maybe thats imposible. So what would be the best implementation to get this to work. First i want to delete all languagecodes in the db and write the new list into it, but it feels a bit dirty to me because maybe some have not to be changed.

```
public void setUserDataForCompany(UserDto userDto) {
    CompanyEntity companyEntity = companyRepository.findById(41).orElseThrow(
        NoSuchElementException::new);
    UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findById(userDto.getUserId()).orElseThrow(
        NoSuchElementException::new);
    companyUserDataMapper.toEntity(userDto, companyEntity, userEntity);

    setLanguagesForUser(userDto, userEntity);
    userRepository.save(userEntity);
}
// Here i have no clue to update existing or store missing languages
private void setLanguagesForUser(UserDto userDto, UserEntity userEntity) {
    userDto.getSelectedLang().forEach(language -> {
        UserlanguageEntity userlanguageEntity = new UserlanguageEntity();
        userlanguageEntity.setLanguagecode(language.getLngCode());
        userEntity.addLanguage(userlanguageEntity);
    });
}
```

Could someone get me a hint to doing it the right way?

Thanks a lot and cheers

Comment: If your json User just has a List of strings, making it seems like overkill to have a UserlanguageEntity entity/java class - all you need is an element collection, with a table containing the language string and the user id. Otherwise, you must configure your model and tell JPA what to do when you clear the list - check out orphanRemoval and CascadeType.REMOVE which you may want to set on the relationship.

Comment: Yeah for sure but I need that entity along with other services and i found that i want to keep it as an extra entity.

Comment: And Orphanremoval is that point that i dont understand i thought that this is the way jpa handel with a list to merge it in the db :/

Comment: If you don't delete entities when they are de-referenced, what do you think should happen to them exactly? JPA will certainly maintain the 'list', but since your table only has a fk field in USERLANGUAGE that is a part of its primary key, you can't exactly treat it like any old entity - it cannot be moved to point at another User. I can only guess at your model since you haven't shown entities or mappings, but it doesn't make sense to me to have USERLANGUAGE be an entity with this table setup. How are you going to map the "English" string to any existing "English" entity, and why bother trying

Comment: Ah ok i got it. I edit the question above with the entities but i think its easier to store only the list like you explained and write a extra repository to get only the languages for specified user. I'll try it and post the result :D